# How to duplicate an entire XML Node and insert it in the XML data using TSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have an XML data where I need to duplicate the contents of a Node as a new Node. There are other nodes in the XML Data and those needs to remain untouched.

I have tried to research by the XML format of the sample nodes is different from what I have. See xml format below

This is my XML Data format:

```
    <Data>
       <ElementA type="list">
          <item key="A" text="Class a- Class A (A)" />
          <item key="AA" text="Class AA - AA(AA)" />
          <item key="B" text="Class B (B)" />
          <item key="C" text="Class C (C)" />
       </ElementA>
       <ElementZ type="list">
          <item key="z" text="Class z- Class z (z)" />
          <item key="y" text="Class y - y(y)" />
          <item key="x" text="Class x (x)" />
        </ElementZ>
    </Data>
```

Unfortunately the XML Data Format I usually see in the internet for their sample looks like this:

```
    <Data>
       <ElementA>text</ElementA>
       <ElementAA>text</ElementAA>
       <ElementB>text</ElementB>
       <ElementC>text</ElementC>
    </Data>
```

This is the expected result I need to do: (Duplicate the Entire Element A as a new Element B with same data set below. Note that Element Z should be untouched.)

```
    <Data>
       <ElementA type="list">
          <item key="A" text="Class a- Class A (A)" />
          <item key="AA" text="Class AA - AA(AA)" />
          <item key="B" text="Class B (B)" />
          <item key="C" text="Class C (C)" />
       </ElementA>
       <ElementB type="list">
          <item key="A" text="Class a- Class A (A)" />
          <item key="AA" text="Class AA - AA(AA)" />
          <item key="B" text="Class B (B)" />
          <item key="C" text="Class C (C)" />
       </ElementB>
       <ElementZ type="list">
          <item key="z" text="Class z- Class z (z)" />
          <item key="y" text="Class y - y(y)" />
          <item key="x" text="Class x (x)" />
       </ElementZ>
    </Data>
```

I am not sure how the List and Item key differs from the usual XML node tagging and can't seem to see many sample of this format in google.

Any help is appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you need:

```
DECLARE @YourXml XML=
N'<Data>
       <ElementA type="list">
          <item key="A" text="Class a- Class A (A)" />
          <item key="AA" text="Class AA - AA(AA)" />
          <item key="B" text="Class B (B)" />
          <item key="C" text="Class C (C)" />
       </ElementA>
  </Data>';

SELECT @YourXml.query('/Data/ElementA/*') AS ElementA
      ,@YourXml.query('/Data/ElementA/*') AS ElementB
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Data');
```

the idea in short:

- The native method `.query()` returns XML-typed fragements according to the given XQuery.
- The `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH` will re-create the xml according to the given names and use `<Data>` as root node.

### UPDATE

The main difference is the order of the nodes after the action

```
DECLARE @YourXml XML=
N'<Data>
       <ElementA type="list">
          <item key="A" text="Class a- Class A (A)" />
          <item key="AA" text="Class AA - AA(AA)" />
          <item key="B" text="Class B (B)" />
          <item key="C" text="Class C (C)" />
       </ElementA>
       <ElementZ type="list">
          <item key="z" text="Class z- Class z (z)" />
          <item key="y" text="Class y - y(y)" />
          <item key="x" text="Class x (x)" />
        </ElementZ>
        <anyOther test="blah"/>
    </Data>';
```

--The old approach, but additionally adding all elements, where the name is different to "ElementA"
--ElementA and ElementB are on top, the rest is behind

```
SELECT @YourXml.query('/Data/ElementA/*') AS ElementA
      ,@YourXml.query('/Data/ElementA/*') AS ElementB
      ,@YourXml.query('/Data/*[local-name()!="ElementA"]') AS [*]
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Data');
```

--The node "ElementA" is added to the bottom, the rest stays untouched

```
SELECT @YourXml.query('/Data/ElementA/*') AS ElementA
      ,@YourXml.query('/Data/ElementA/*') AS ElementB
      ,@YourXml.query('/Data/*[local-name()!="ElementA"]') AS [*]
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Data');
```

--XQuery/FLWOR approach adding the content of  as  at the end

```
SELECT @YourXml.query('
                      <Data>
                      {
                      for $nd in /Data/*
                      return $nd
                      }
                      <ElementB>
                      {
                        /Data/ElementA/*
                      }
                      </ElementB>
                      </Data>   
                      ')
```

--XQuery/FLWOR with a specific location

```
SELECT @YourXml.query('
                      <Data>
                      {
                      for $nd in /Data/*
                      return
                      if(local-name($nd)="ElementA") then
                         ($nd, <ElementB>{$nd/*}</ElementB>)
                      else
                          $nd
                      }
                      </Data>   
                      ')
```

--The node to duplicate is taken with the new name

```
DECLARE @elementB XML=@YourXml.query('<ElementB>{/Data/ElementA/*}</ElementB>');
-- ... and is inserted on a specific position
SET @YourXml.modify('insert sql:variable("@elementB") after (/Data/ElementA)[1]');
SELECT @YourXml;
```

Check them out, one of them should be okay :-)

Comment: Thanks Shungo!  I modified my example a bit as I missed looking at the data.
There are other xml nodes that cannot be touched. see updated sample above. I'M wondering if it's still doable or will need to have a different set of code to do now. I'm thinking after applying your Code, I will do a REPLACE in my QUERY and then it will use the duplicated code for the XML.

something like this:
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(@YourXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), CAST(@oldXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), CAST(@NewXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))

Answer (score 0):

By using XQuery FLWOR expression:

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML= 
N'<Data>
       <ElementA type="list">
          <item key="A" text="Class a- Class A (A)" />
          <item key="AA" text="Class AA - AA(AA)" />
          <item key="B" text="Class B (B)" />
          <item key="C" text="Class C (C)" />
       </ElementA>
  </Data>';

SELECT @xml.query('<Data>{
for $x in /Data/ElementA
return ($x, <ElementB>{$x/*}</ElementB>)
}</Data>');
```